# MERN router links dont work when manually typing in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-router

I deployed my MERN stack app to heroku but the router paths dont work when i manually type in the url paths. 
This is my node server:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

// //connect DB
connectDB();

app.use('/api/poll', require('./routes/api/poll'));

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    app.use(express.static( 'client/build' ));

    app.get('*', () => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')); //relative path
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started ${PORT}`));
```

This is the router in react:

```
<Router>
  <Fragment>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
      <Route exact path="/create" component={CreatePoll} />
      <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
      <Route exact path="/404" component={NoMatch} />
      <Route exact path="/:id" component={Poll} />
      <Route exact path="/:id/results" component={Results} />
    </Switch>
    <NotificationContainer />
  </Fragment>
</Router>
```

Basically if I type in a pathname in my browser url, for example, baseUrl/poll/vote, it doesnt work. Only if I type in the link it does that. If I get to that path by my app redirects, then it works.

Comment: Are you using `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter` in your React frontend?

Comment: @jered BrowserRouter

Comment: Try using `HashRouter` instead. It will add a `#` to part of your URLs but that's generally fine. Do you specifically need `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @jered I dont need it specifically i just never heard of hashrouter. When redirecting pages to link i would need to add a # to the beginning of the link right?

Comment: It would probably look something like `baseUrl/#/poll/vote` etc.

Comment: Cool if your question is answered please mark the answer below as "accepted" to clear it from the queue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Router` needs to be an instance of `HashRouter`, not `BrowserRouter`.

`import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router';`

`BrowserRouter` needs special configuration and consideration on the backend to handle network requests to routes that, in fact, should be handled by the frontend.

`HashRouter` is easier to use because it inserts a `#` into the URL, effectively sending all page requests to the same base route without the server needing to do anything special.